# How to specify ODATA filter query for the salesforce connector in Microsoft Flow

Tags: date, filter, odata, power-automate

I'm having difficulty determining the correct format for a date (not a datetime) expression. In this situation, CloseDate from the Opportunity table.

I have tried multiple formats, including quotes, no quotes, timezones, no timezones.  I have this working in regular REST queries just using the date in format yyyy-MM-dd without quotes,

A couple of examples..

**CloseDate le 2011-12-31**

ERROR: *Salesforce failed to complete task: Message: FROM Opportunity WHERE (CloseDate <= 2011-12-31T00:00:00.0000000+00:00)\n                                       ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:6368\nvalue of filter criterion for field 'CloseDate' must be of type date and should not be enclosed in quotes\r\nclientRequestId: 50c8ea4a-bd02-4e95-919c-df02074f3144",*

**CloseDate ge '2017-01-01'**

ERROR: *value of filter criterion for field 'CloseDate' must be of type date and should not be enclosed in quotes*

**CloseDate ge datetime'2017-01-01'**

ERROR: *inner exception: Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal*

Help!  Has anyone worked out how to specify the format for a "date" field in an ODATA filter?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE : FEB 11 2020 : I have worked w Microsoft support and this bug is fixed!**

You can now filter against date fields or date time fields.  Previously filters against date fields failed because flow converted to datetime and sfdc specifies that [date fields cannot be queried as datetime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

**ORIG POST:**

I have been poking on this and it looks like msft flow / power automate can only query dateTime fields in salesforce, but not date fields.

i can filter createdDate gt 2020-01-01 with no issues, but cannot query closeDate or any custom date field (flow will not run successfully - throws an error as above).  custom datetime field works fine.

the only workaround i have found is to use relative dates - THIS_MONTH, LAST_MONTH etc work fine. (shocking!) that is quite helpful.

however the LAST_N_DAYS:N style does not work, the colon appears to break things.

i have opened a case with microsoft support as it appears that their connector transforms all dates to datetime, and the [salesforce docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) specify that date fields cannot be queried as datetime

> A fieldExpression uses different date formats for date and dateTime fields. If you specify a dateTime format in a query, you can filter only on dateTime fields. Similarly, if you specify a date format value, you can filter only on date fields.:

Comment: msft support has confirmed as a bug and is working on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issues querying the relative days in power flow,power flow had a handy function to resolve this,

```
 LastModifiedDate ge @{getPastTime(7,'Day','yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

This works well for me